# What is the syntax for private method in browser Javascript class(not node.js)?

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6

I know this question has been asked for many times, however, most of them are either for the Node.js solutions or does not work in the browsers.

So, is it possible to implement a private method in browser javascript class?

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <script>
            class Happy
            {
                constructor()
                {
                }
                _leo()
                {
                    console.log("ff");
                }
            }       
            var h=new Happy();
            h._leo();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, the above code still outputs "ff" in the console, how can I fix it?

Comment: There are no private methods in JavaScript. You can hide a function in a closure; you can hide method's key (as a symbol) in a closure; you can't hide a method (though both ways are commonly used to fake it).

Comment: There’s a [stage 3](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-instance_class_fields_private_instance_class_fields_basic_support) [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields) to add a `#someMethod(){}` syntax.

Comment: Is it possible to provide some examples for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This illustrates how to hide a method name, effectively making the method uncallable outside the hiding closure:

```
const Klass = (function() {
  const privName = Symbol("priv");

  class Klass {
    publ() {
      console.log("in publ");
      this[privName]();
    }
    [privName]() {
      console.log("in priv");
    }
  }

  return Klass;
})()

let inst = new Klass();
inst.publ();
// => in publ
//    in priv
```

It uses the fact that `Symbol()` returns an entity that cannot be replicated, the fact that `privName` is not exposed anywhere outside the closure, and the fact that we can define properties with calculated names using the square bracket notation.

Unlike the function-hiding mechanism demonstrated by ultratoad, this is not just a helper function, it is a true method. Just note that you can't call it using the dot notation - dot notation only works when you know the name, and here, no-one does except `privName`.

Comment: `privName` may not be exported, but you can always get the symbol with `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(Klass.prototype)`. It is well hidden and can't collide, which are huge benefits, but it isn't technically private.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Huh, didn't know that. On the other hand... Meh. Ruby's `private` is one `send` away; Pythonistas just trust other people will be too lazy to type an underscore. I'll take it.

Comment: Totally, depending on your goal, this approach will be 100% acceptable.